# Understanding COQ proof on Show Proof.

Tags: coq, proof

Im new in COQ and Im trying to proof the counterexample theorem.

```
Variable A B:Prop.

Hypothesis R1: ~A->B.
Hypothesis R2: ~B.

Theorem ej: A.
```

When we studied logics, we learn the RAA thechnic but in COQ this doesn't add a new Hypothesis, and now we are stuck.

So then we try:

```
Proof.
tauto.
Show Proof.
```

With the following output, but we don't have any idea what does it mean.

```
(NNPP A
   (fun H : ~ A => let H0 : B := R1 H in let H1 : False := R2 H0 in False_ind False H1))
```

Can anybody help us to understand the COQ Show Proof output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coq represents proofs as programs of a functional programming language, following the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).  These programs are written by combining the primitives of Coq's logic with axioms and theorems proved by the user.  The output that you see is a "program" that invokes the axiom `NNPP` on two arguments, the proposition `A` and the anonymous function `fun H : ~ A => ...`.  The axiom `NNPP` is the principle of dougle-negation elimination usually used in proofs by contradiction.  If you type `Check NNPP.`, Coq tells you that its type is `forall P : Prop, ~ ~ P -> P`, which means that, given any proposition `P` and any proof `H` of `~ ~ P`, `NNPP P H` is a proof of `P`.  The functional term that Coq built above, `fun H : ~ A => ...`, is precisely a Coq proof of `~ ~ A` that uses the hypothesis you declared.

I don't know how much prior experience you have with Coq and functional programming, but it might be useful to have a look at the [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) book series, which gives a comprehensive introduction to Coq.  In particular, the [Proof Objects](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/ProofObjects.html) chapter describes how Coq proofs are represented.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful to understand how can I prove my theorems